# What's "stetig fortsetzbar" in English?

Tags: translation-request

If, say, a function $f\colon(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and there's a continuous function $g\colon[a,b)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f$ and $g$ agree on $(a,b)$, then some German textbooks call $f$ "stetig fortsetzbar" in $a$, and $g$ is called the "stetige Fortsetzung".  Of course, "stetig" is for continuous, but is there a standard English term for this concept?  Is it maybe "continuously continuable"?

[FWIW, the more general definition is that a function $f$ defined on a set $D$ is "stetig fortsetzbar" in $x_0\neq D$ if $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ (is defined and) exists.]

Comment: 'Continuous extension', I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

stetige Fortsetzung: *continuous extension*

stetig fortsetzbar: *continuously extensible*

Comment: Oh boy, "extension" somehow didn't come to mind, but a quick web search seems to confirm this.  That's interesting because the translation of "analytische Fortsetzung" is "analytic continuation" and not "analytic extension".

Comment: ... you cannot translate too literally ... *Fortsetzung* has two (or more) English translations. Outside mathematics you can use whatever translation you wish.  But in mathematics, we fix certain terminology and always say it the same way.

Comment: @GEdgar Correct, the German word *Fortsetzung* has a range of meanings depending on the context (continuation, sequel, extension, instalment, ...). When used in mathematics it normally means *extension*. Similarly the word "stetig" can mean constant, steady, continuous, ... The combination "stetige Fortsetzung" is only used in  mathematics (at least I have never heard it in another context) and it means *continuous extension*. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortsetzungssatz_von_Tietze.

Comment: @GEdgar Of course I know that one cannot simply translate and that there's a fixed terminology in mathematics.  That's why I asked here in the first place.  If I had just needed an English translation for the word "Fortsetzung", well, I have a dictionary at home...

Comment: Plus: "continuous continuation" would be strange.